# Does anyone know why my bone name won't show up in the bone tab for the target when doing constraints?

Tags: bones, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to make an IK bone, but it won't show up in the constraints tab, I press the target and go to the armature, then I press the bone tab and the name won't show up, does that for the rest of my bones now too. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: hello, maybe share the armature? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Two ipothesis: 1 you didn't choose the right armature, in which the bones are. 2 there are some letters in the search area, so the tab is showing only bones that have thoose letters in their name (maybe none).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I meant to comment and say I figured it out, and it was just as you said, Josh the armature was named different. But now, I made an IK foot book and it moves the entire body while bending the foot. Anyone have any idea's why this is happening?